# Construction of Past tense in English

Tags: sentence-meaning

I want to say to my colleague that, a few years back, he and I were working in same building.

Should I say:

> This is the same building where we were working.

or

> This is the same building where we had been working.

or

> This is the same building we would work.

or

> This is the same building we worked.

I am confused. Please bear with me and explain in simple terms.

Comment: I assume that both you and him don't work there anymore. If that's the case, I would say, *"This is the same building we (both) were working in."*

Comment: I'd go for *This is the same building we worked in.*

Answer (score 2):

As Steve Meinkoff says, the conventional way to say it is, "We used to work in the same building."

One could also say, "We worked in the same building." Leaving out the "used to" de-emphasizes the fact that it is in the past, but that should still be apparent from the past tense.

Note that if you say, "This is the same building where we worked", you are no longer saying "you and I worked in the same building", but rather that this building here, the building that you are somehow identifying, is the same building as the one where you worked. That is, you have shifted from saying that you and I worked in the same building to saying that this building is the one that we worked in, as opposed to the two of us working together in some other building.

The various sentences you give are all different tenses. In this case the difference in meaning in fairly subtle.

> This is the same building where we were working.

We worked there at some specific time in the past, as opposed to just generally in the past.

> This is the same building where we had been working.

We worked there at some specific time in the past that preceded some other event in the past. Typically "had been Xing" is used with an identification of some other event. Like, "This is the same building where we had been working when Sally arrived."

> This is the same building we would work.

Now you are saying that you worked the building, as opposed to working IN the building. This probably isn't what you mean, as we don't normally speak of "working a building". (It is possible, though. Salesman will talk of "working a building" meaning that they are making sales pitches to people in that building.)

> This is the same building we worked.

Again, you are working the building rather than working in the building.

Answer (score 1):

All the examples contain the word "this", which implies that you're standing outside the building in question, or maybe looking at a picture of it.

Either way, it's obvious which building you're talking about, which makes the word "same" redundant.

So you could just point at the building, and say:

> We used to work here.

"Used to" indicates something that was true in the past, but isn't now.

If you're not in a position to specify which building it was, you might instead say:

> We used to work in the same building.

Answer (score 1):

Though for all four versions, constructing the sentences like that suggest that you are going to talk about something else that was ongoing at the same time, like

> This is the same building we would work in when our other site was
>   closed for repair.

The 'would' suggests that you are going to further explicate with some condition that was operating when you were working in that building.

The second sentence has a similar issue; using the "were were working" as opposed to "we worked" suggests that you are also going to talk about some event which happened at the same time period you were working in that building.

> This is the same building where we were working when we heard about 9-11.

I think for your purpose, it would be simpler for you to just say

> We used to work in that building.

or

> We used to work in the same building

"Used to" means that you don't work there anymore.  (And "used" in this context is pronounced more like "yoost", instead of "yoozed")